# why the table is giving output like this?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-insert

I was setting a mcq question paper of an online test. So the table for storing the question and options have fields like this :

```
question_id -PRIMARY KEY ,question_description varchar(1000),option_a -varchar(100),option_b -varchar(100) ,option_c -varchar(100),option_d -varchar(100),answer -(int)
```

The question that I am trying to set is

```
Q) a and b volumes of solutions of concentration x% and y% respectively  by volume are mixed to form a new solution of resultant concentration z%. If it is known that z is less than the average of x and y, then:
1) a>b if x>y   2) a>b if x<y  3) a<b if x>=y  4) a<b if x<y
```

so when I am inserting it into the table the options are not coming in proper way. It is coming like this :

```
Q) a and b volumes of solutions of concentration x% and y% respectively by volume are mixed to form a new solution of resultant concentration z%. If it is known that z is less than the average of x and y, then:

1) a>b if x>y 2) a>b if x 3) a=y 4) a
```

Why this kind of output is coming?

1)a>b if x>y

2)a>b if x
3)a=y

4)a

The insert statement was like this :

```
INSERT INTO table_name(question_description,option_a,option_b,option_c,option_d,answer)
VALUES('Q) a and b volumes of solutions of concentration x% and y% respectively by volume are mixed to form a new solution of resultant concentration z%. If it is known that z is less than the average of x and y, then:','a>b if x>y   ','a>b if x<y  ','a<b if x>=y  ','a<b if x<y  ','1');
```

and the select statement is like this (this was question number 5)

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE  question_id = '5';
```

Comment: Please add your insert statement.And your select statement.

Comment: How do you insert the data? And how do you show/view it?

Comment: Given that the missing parts are all enclosed by <> tags, I suggest it is something about how you are passing the arguments between whatever your front end and whatever your back end is. If they are passed as xml then there is a nested tag `<y  3) a<b if x>` and then an unterminated tag starting with `<b if x<y `

Comment: @P.Salmon here i have added my insert statement and select statement in the question. please help me

Comment: There is no problem with either your insert or select at the mysql end. Where are you presenting the query output?

Comment: @P.Salmon i am presenting my query output at the test interface page which is written in php.

Comment: I once set this same question in a online exam host platform also..there also the same problem happened in the output section. I used this question 2 months earlier in the "typeform" platform.

Answer (score 1):

No idea, but given

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(question_id int PRIMARY KEY ,
question_description varchar(1000),
option_a varchar(100),
option_b varchar(100) ,
option_c varchar(100),
option_d varchar(100),
answer int
);
insert into t values
(
1,
'a and b volumes of solutions of concentration x% and y% respectively  by volume are mixed to form a new solution of resultant concentration z%. If it is known that z is less than the average of x and y, then:',
'a>b if x>y',
'a>b if x<y',
'a<b if x>=y',
'a<b if x<y',
null
) 

select * from t;

+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+
| question_id | question_description                                                                                                                                                                                             | option_a   | option_b   | option_c    | option_d   | answer |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+
|           1 | a and b volumes of solutions of concentration x% and y% respectively  by volume are mixed to form a new solution of resultant concentration z%. If it is known that z is less than the average of x and y, then: | a>b if x>y | a>b if x<y | a<b if x>=y | a<b if x<y |   NULL |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As expected. IF you are doing something different you need to tell us.